# Evangelising time

Tags: discussion

So some people may have realised [some of the other beta sites are being shut down](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/).  I was shocked too.

The thought of this happening to Travel scared me a little, especially since I've been off it a bit the last few weeks while moving countries.

So anyway, I think it's high time we start to push it socially, because the small amount of effort that would take is nothing compared to the countless hours many of us have spent writing answers and editing and sorting and so on for the many questions we have here.

We're growing slowly, and certainly have a community of such - join the chat room every so often and there's usually some casual banter going on every few hours - just a few more people and it'll practically have someone there all the time ;)

So this post is to ask what we can do to try and promote the site.  I've played with submitting some of the more interesting questions (and answers) to digg, tweeted some, put others on reddit - certainly that seems to generate some extra traffic, but it'd be useful to know if anyone else has suggestions or thoughts on how to extend this?

In the meanwhile, if you have a social media account - twitter, Facebook, Stumbleupon, Digg, Reddit, Hacker News or anything else, or a travel blog where you could do a post about it, it's time to get the word out that we have a great thing here.

Thoughts welcome.

**EDIT**

Wow, Astronomy and Theoretical Physics had all their questions migrated to Physics.  They've got their work cut out for them in terms of re-tagging :)

I would love to see their traffic stats for the week or two around the migration...

Comment: What were the closed sites' stats?

Comment: I only looked at Astronomy, they have 350ish a day, although that'll change this week as lots of people go have a look just like I did.  Economics is 240 a day. They're all linked in the blog piece I linked to.

Comment: So their stats are really a lot more worse than ours, but however, I fully support your opinion!

Comment: They mention steady growth and our site has very steady - close to linear growth on just about all stats - and I have the graph to prove it! d-:

Comment: Agreed - although our questions per day are seemingly decreasing at present.  And that's the problem Astronomy had - ending on 0.8 a day :/

Comment: I will risk a statement that the SE staff, of which a few are travelers themselves, is unlikely to close this site :)

Answer (score 9):

According to [our stats at Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel), all we need is not the *interesting* questions, but simply questions - there are only 4.6 a day, and this stat are only decreasing.

Also we have to answer more often even to answered questions - just to move the "Answers per question" rate.

Visits per day are move up slowly, but constantly, and there wouldn't be any problems with that.

So I think our problem is not with new users, but in content quality. May be we need another flash-mob for answering the questions.

Comment: Yes and we should probably renew the question topic days and place them a little bit more prominent.

Comment: But please no "fluff" questions or answers to prop up the numbers!

Comment: Content *quality*, or content *quantity*?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm quality/

Comment: Starting to look much better now, with 9.2 questions / day! Visits / day is also up significantly (1,830; was around 1,500 not long ago).

Comment: yeah (cough) - http://travel.stackexchange.com/badges/59/announcer seems to help a bit ;)

Comment: @Mark Mayo SPAMER!

Answer (score 2):

Some sites were closed because of the depletion of the question pool. This was the case of very specific, narrow-field sites such as **Atheism**, where the community failed to produce new questions.

In my opinion, the topic of the **Travel** site is very large, so the site will not become saturated with questions. The danger is, however, the lack of the activity of the users. There are thousends of possible questions which could be asked, but the users are not asking them. There are a lot of travel portals, so if users become satisfied by what they found there, they won't ask their question here.

When it comes to the new users, I think the **question pool** is still too limited to motivate users external to StackExchange to join. And it is our responsibility to create such question pool, that the site will become at minimum some kind of **Travel FAQ**.

As for the question promotion in portals such as **Digg**, the digging of already submited links is very easy, but the submitting new one is a bit tricky - you must provide the description, category etc. Isn't it possible to automate that process so that the diggs would be consequest and manual submitting wouldn't be required? It would be also great to have **Digg button** on the left panel.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Atheism one, but personally was surprised that Astronomy got closed.

Comment: As for automating, I'm not about to try that, I have a full-time job these days for coding ;)  As for having the digg button, that's up to Stackexchange and I suspect they've considered and decided not to, otherwise they could have digg, stumbleupon, reddit, pinterest and many more - I guess they're trying the ones that work the best?

Comment: I think they are also considering, if digging etc. should be so easy, and what consequence would have flooding such portals with diggs, stumbles etc. for 50% of all questions or more...