# Why was this question on the kinds of places in Singapore that require visitors to present their physical passport closed as a list question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [What kinds of places in Singapore require visitors to present their physical passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185083/1810) was closed because it is a list question. However, from my understanding [What qualifies as a "list" question and what doesn't?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/799/1810), if the question is well-defined and that there is a reasonably small number of possible answers, then the question shouldn't be closed as a list question.

As the answer to the question [What kinds of places in Singapore require visitors to present their physical passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185083/1810) shows, there are only about 4 such kinds of places (accommodations, medical, massage, places serving alcohol). I believe that qualified as a reasonably small number of possible answers. By comparison, to take another recent question, [Which currencies are accepted for the visa on arrival in Laos, and what is the price in each currency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185110/1810) likely has 3 answers and was well received. And there are many questions with much larger list that were well received and not closed, e.g.:

- [When and why do people clap/applaud after a plane lands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68259/1810)
- [Why would you wrap your luggage in plastic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3220/1810)
- [How to make dining alone less awkward?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/59671/1810)
- [Where in the world can I travel with a COVID vaccine passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162548/1810)
- [Where can I take a selfie with kangaroos in Australia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51259/1810)
- [Where can I find publicly accessible paternoster elevators?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/115486/1810)
- [Where can I go to avoid planes overhead?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137619/1810)
- [(Where) Can I go to a "sleeper" cinema?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/42540/1810)
- [Where can I see the Milky Way in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/103807/1810)
- [Are Ginkgo trees in Japan rare and if so, where can I find them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76758/1810)

Comment: You know the answer, someone voted to close, others followed. Please vote to reopen, asking here is only useful in that we see it. Using open questions as examples is not relevant.

Comment: @RoryAlsop aside from increased visibility, another use of posting here is improving closure consistency and being able to explain why I think the question deserved to be reopened. Open questions as examples are relevant to show how vague policies are actually enforced.

Comment: We have been round that discussion many times with you Franck, and you must be aware by now that the way you go about it seems to reduce your chances of getting things reopened, and acquires downvotes. Open questions as examples are in almost all cases irrelevant. They do not help your argument at all.. The correct route is voting to reopen.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Revenge close and down votes and as well as revenge reviews are strictly against SE policies. I also assume that moderation is supposed to be unbiased (which it mostly is on Travel SE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question [What kinds of places in Singapore require visitors to present their physical passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185083/1810) was reopened. I think it's good to keep this meta question as it gives some concrete examples of empirically acceptable list questions.